# Linux process automatically starts again with new new PID after killing

Tags: nginx, nodejs, amazon-ec2

I want to stop Node server on Linux, but when I try to stop it, it automatically starts again with a new PID. How can I stop this completely? Here you can see I tried to stop Nginx and Node process.

[image: node server]

I have tried tried these commands:

```
kill pid
Kill -9 pid
killall node <<command not working
killall -s KILL node <<< not working
```

When I tried to kill process 3814 it shows error No such process, how can I stop node server???

Comment: typically because there is a parent process ( unknown here )  which is listening to its child  ( nodejs server ) and when child gets killed parent launches another child ...  `ps -auxww | grep node`   then look for the PID of node and column to right is PID of parent ... once parent PID is identified then do a grep on parent PID ... ps -auxww | grep xxxparent_pid_herexxx`  then once parent process is identified kill its PID

Comment: @ScottStensland I got this output by ps --auxww | grep node    Output -> root      4177  0.6  3.5 1018772 141344 ?      Ssl  11:10   0:13 node /root/only4laughproject/server.js
root      5132  0.0  0.0 119420   912 pts/2    S+   11:46   0:00 grep --color=auto node

Comment: @ScottStensland it is same output as ps aux | grep node output as above attached image.

Comment: output format of ps is different across various OS flavors ... conceptually what I said holds just research column headers of ps output to find parent PID column ... debian ( ubuntu,etc ) based OS adheres to the child parent columns side by side ... your OS ps format may vary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the output of `ps`. Your first command, `sudo systemctl stop nginx` is the right way to stop a running service and did actually work. The line you see in the `ps` isn't a running `nginx` process, that is the `grep` process you launched:

```
$ ps aux | grep foo
terdon    642773  0.0  0.0   8944  2384 pts/23   S+   13:40   0:00 grep --color foo
```

When you run `ps | grep`, that is a process so that is also included in the output of `ps`. And, since your `grep` contains the string `nginx`, the `grep` itself is included in the output of `grep`. The usual ways around this are:

1. Use `pgrep` instead of `grep`

   ```
    pgrep nginx
   ```

   That will only return anything (a list of PIDs) if there is a running `nginx` process.
2. Use a character class in `grep` so that you can still match the process, but will ignore grep itself:

   ```
    ps aux | grep '[n]ginx'
   ```

Because the `grep` process now contains `[n]ginx` instead of `nginx`, it will not be matched by itself.

Since these are set up as services and, presumably, set to launch automatically, killing them just makes them restart. To stop them, you should always use `systemctl stop nginx` or, if your system supports it `service nginx stop`.